# Analysis Service. Performance issue when I process dimension second time

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssas, olap, olap-cube

I am working with Analytics app which can build and process DM and Cube. User can select  dimensions/attributes/measures/hierarchies they want to see in Cube.

My cube loading/processing flow when I **first time** create and load cube

1) Create DS, DSV, dimensions, cube structures
2) Process Full dimensions
3) Process Full cube

After that user may change dimension structure (add/delete attributes) and I have to update and reload cube **second time**, flow:

1) Update dimensions, cube structures
2) Process Full dimensions
3) Process Full cube

I have performance issue when I do Process Full second time on dimensions because it reprocess related measure groups and partitions.

Any suggestion I can change my flow structure will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Simple yet efficient change, as per Microsoft recommends, always "process data" then "process indexes" instead of "full process". Reference : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966525.aspx